# Code for sending emails from Moodle Forum

Tags: moodle

Can someone know where is code for sending emails from forum? When someone replay on the some post in forum the user received emails, I need to change this email and will be very grateful if some one tell me where is code  (function) from where is send this email.

Best Regards,
Jordan

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you may need to utilise the built in function 'email_to_user' found in /lib/moodlelib.php.

```
function email_to_user($user, $from, $subject, $messagetext, $messagehtml = '', $attachment = '', $attachname = '',
                       $usetrueaddress = true, $replyto = '', $replytoname = '', $wordwrapwidth = 79)
```